# How to direct to jsp page when button click onclick event

Tags: html

I need to direct to one jsp page from one jsp on button click onclick event.I have one simple form called add-metadata.jsp In this file I have some form elements and one button too.when I click this I need to redirect to another jsp file as add-metadata-finish.jsp

already that main form action event is directed to another jsp file but I need to direct my jsp file only for button click.

How can I do this ?

Comment: on click try `window.location.replace("your url string");` or
`window.location.href = "your url string";`[Read More](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-can-i-make-a-redirect-page-in-jquery-javascript)

Comment: This question has been asked a lot. Check out http://css-tricks.com/redirect-web-page/. I think you could simply do something like `<button onclick="window.location = '/new-webpage.jsp';">`. Make sure to search around SO, though, before asking a question, because your question has likely been answered already somewhere else.